# Matlab - plot the points contained in slice of alphaShape

Tags: matlab

Using Matlab, I'm trying to calculate and plot points which are contained in z-slices of this shape:
[image: Overall view]

It is a pyramid at a 45deg angle with the top removed.

When I take a slice at z=198 (a bit below the datatip above), I get a weird artifact:
[image: Slice]

Here is my code snippet doing the checking:

```
% Setup alphaShape as "alpha" ....
points = 1e3 * [0.3223    0.1761    0.3299
    0.5752    1.2034   -0.0618
   -0.0172    1.2034   -0.0618
    0.2357    0.1761    0.3299
    0.3223    0.0671    0.2209
    0.5752    0.4588   -0.8064
   -0.0172    0.4588   -0.8064
    0.2357    0.0671    0.2209];
alpha = alphaShape(points);

% Then, check if coordinates on slice are in or outside alpha

z = 198;
width = 550;
depth = 450;
inout = zeros(width,depth);
for qx = 1:width
   for qy = 1:depth
      in = inShape(alpha,qx,qy,z);
      if (in)
         inout(qx,qy) = 1;
      end
   end
end

% Plot
figure; contourf(inout.'); % Not sure why conjugate needed?
```

Can anyone point out what is causing the extra "peg" sticking out of my slice result?  Or how to fix my code to remove it?

EDIT: Using `plot(alpha)`, the square top is not connected to the base the way I thought:
[image: alpha plot]
My initial plot was done with:

`K = convhull(points);
figure;trisurf(K,points(:,1),points(:,2),points(:,3),'Facecolor','red','FaceAlpha',0.1);`

Comment: Is your `alpha` correct? What is `qz`, do you mean `z`? Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will help you get help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was how I created my alphaShape.

Using the builtin `convhull()` function and `inhull()` from the Matlab File Exchange gave the results I desire.